# Extracting Digits from an Integer in C?

Tags: c, integer-division

```
void print(int num, int digits)
{
    double mod, divi;
    int mod1, divi1;
    mod = pow(10, digits);
    divi = pow(10, digits-1);
    mod1 = (int)mod;
    divi1 = (int)divi;

    if(digits > 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ((num%mod1)/divi1));
        digits--;
        print(num, digits);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This function is meant to print the digits from `num` vertically, however when I run it the only thing it prints are 0's. I know it gets the correct number of digits because it prints the same number of zeroes as there are digits in the number, so something must be wrong with my use of Modulo or Division here, and I can't quite seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

The function to get the numbers(maybe the problem is here?):

```
void getNum()
{   
    int num, digits=0;
    printf("Enter a number to be printed vertically: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num < 0)
    {
        digits = 1;
    }
    while(num)
    {
        num = num/10; //Here was the problem. Num was 0 once i passed it to print()
        digits++; //Simply added a new variable to fix it. Thanks all!
    }

    print(num, digits);
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What are your inputs?

Comment: `pow()` may return a value just under the expected integer value.  Better to round the result `round(pow(10,digits));` before truncating to an `int`.  Be sure to first `#include <math.h>`

Comment: I would just input random numbers of any length and always get all 0's, the same number as the number of digits.

Comment: Maybe the function I just added is where the error lies. (Getting the numbers)

Comment: Well, looking at it I realize how stupid I am. I set num equal to 0 before passing it to the function. My apologies!

Comment: @abzib Post your solution as an answer and accept it.  You may up-vote all other useful answers once your rep is 15+.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, except that it's much too complicated and unnecessarily uses floating-point maths.

Here is an alternative:

```
void print(int num, int digits)
{
    if (digits > 0) {
        print(num / 10, digits - 1);
        printf("%d\n", num % 10);
    }
}
```

The trick is to move the printing *after* the recursive call. This allows for much simpler logic.

Comment: This has an interesting output when `num < 0`.  But so does OP's.

Comment: I copy-pasted this into my code and still got all 0's strangely...I've edited the above to add my getNum function, perhaps the problem lies there?

Comment: @abzib: Yes, the problem is there. You modify `num` until it becomes zero, and then call print on its new zero value.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, May not important but add this condition in the beginning solve that. `if (num<0){
  num *=-1; 
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for my problem. I was setting `num` to `0` before passing it to the function. I simply declared another variable `num1` to use in the while loop instead of the actual `num` which is passed to the function.

***Code***

```
void getNum()
{   

    int num, num1, digits=0;
    //get the num
    printf("Enter a number to be printed vertically: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    num1 = num;

    //Loop to find how many digits are in the number
    while(num1)
    {
        num1 = num1/10;
        digits++;
    }
    //call function to print
    print(num, digits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By little change on [NPE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26349454/7508077) I reach to version of code that eliminate `digits` argument and works for negative numbers.

---

***Code***

```
void print(int num)
{
    if (num < 0){
        num *=-1; 
    }

    if (num > 0) {
        print(num / 10);
        printf("%d\n", num % 10);
    }
}
```

---

**[Edit1 and 2]**: *Correct `INT_MIN` overflow*

Thanks for chux for his constructive comments I correct potential INT_MIN negation overflow. [Another similar topic by chux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641296/7508077) .

```
void print(int num)
{

    #if INT_MIN < -INT_MAX
    ///In two's complements systems.
    ///handle special case

    if ( num == INT_MIN ) {
      //fprintf(stderr, "Houston, we have a problem\n");

      // Maybe return or exit here.
      //~ 2147483647 -> 2147483648
      print(INT_MAX/10);
      print(INT_MIN%10); //portable version ///print(8);
      return;
    }

    if (num < 0){   
            //num =-((unsigned)num);
            num *=-1; 
    }

    #endif  

    if (num > 0) {
        print(num / 10);      
        printf("%d\n",  num%10);
    }

}
```

---

Now if we call `print()`

```
int number = INT_MIN;// a negative number

print(-120);
printf("\n");
print(-321);

print(number);
```

---

Output

```
1
2
0

3
2
1
Houston, we have a problem
```

**[Edit3]**

Change code to work for also `print(0)`.

```
int zeroSignal=1;

void print(int num)
{

    #if INT_MIN < -INT_MAX
    ///In two's complements systems.
    ///handle special case

    if ( num == INT_MIN ) {
      ///fprintf(stderr, "Houston, we have a problem\n");
      // Maybe return or exit here.
      //~ 2147483647 -> 2147483648
      print(INT_MAX/10);
      print(INT_MIN%10); //portable version ///print(8);
      return;
    }

    if (num < 0){   
            //num =-((unsigned)num);
            num *=-1; 
    }

    #endif  


    if (num==0 && zeroSignal){
        printf("Only zero: %d\n", 0);
    }

    if (num > 0) {
        zeroSignal = 0;
        print(num / 10);
        printf("%d\n",  num%10);
    }

    zeroSignal = 1;      
}
```

In above code I use global integer `zeroSignal` to implement a way that works for `print(0)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, OK. I think now it handle `- INT_MIN`.

Comment: `print(8);` assumes `INT_MIN == -2147483648`.  That assumption is not needed nor portable programming.  Consider `print(INT_MIN%10);` and drop the `fprintf(stderr, ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
int print(int num, int digits)
{
    int min = 0;
    if (digits > 0) {
        min = print(num / 10, digits - 1);
        if(num %10)
           printf("%s%d\n", num < 0 && !(min++) ? "-" : "", abs(num % 10));
    }
    return min;
}

int print1(int num, int digits)
{
    int min = 0;
    if (digits > 0) {
        min = print1(num / 10, digits - 1);
        if(num %10)
        {
            printf("%s", num < 0 && !(min++) ? "-\n" : "");
            printf("%u\n", abs(num % 10));
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    print(-1234, 9);
    printf("\n-------------\n\n");
    print1(-23456565, 9);
}
```