# Is negating INT_MIN undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, c89

Let's say I have a variable `i` that comes from external sources:

```
int i = get_i();
```

Assuming `i` is `INT_MIN` and two's complement representation, is `-i` undefined?

Comment: Answer 2 of this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917233/why-does-int-min-int-min-in-a-signed-twos-complement-representation

Comment: If you try to generate a rvalue that it's type can not represent, then it's UB.

Comment: Short answer: **Yes, it is undefined behavior**.  The answers below provide nice details but kind of beat around the bush.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the platform. C supports three representations for negative numbers (see [section 6.2.6.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.6.2) of the C99 standard):

- Two's complement.
- One's complement.
- Sign and magnitude.

With one's complement and sign and magnitude, `-INT_MIN` is defined (and equal to `INT_MAX`). With two's complement, it depends on whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero is a trap representation or a normal value. If it's a normal value, `-INT_MIN` overflows, resulting in undefined behavior (see [section 6.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5p5) of the C99 standard). If it's a trap representation, `-INT_MIN` equals `INT_MAX`.

That said, most modern platforms use two's complement without trap representations, so `-INT_MIN` typically results in undefined behavior.

Comment: The last paragraph seems unclear to me, I think you are trying to say that if `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX` then `-INT_MIN == INT_MAX`, otherwise `-INT_MIN` is undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M What I'm trying to say is under which conditions exactly `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX` and that this condition can even be true on a two's complement platform (at least theoretically).

Comment: I spent a while looking in the wrong parts of sections 6.2.6.2 and 6.5 searching for the statement that `-INT_MIN`  is undefined behavior. I did eventually find it (I think), in item 6.5-5, which says "If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @pnkfelix that only matters if `-INT_MIN` falls outside the range of values an integer can represent. If you're using sign-magnitude or ones-complement, `-INT_MIN` is within the range of values an integer can represent, so `-INT_MIN` is perfectly fine. Of course, it's undefined behaviour if it overflows, as it would with twos-complement.

Answer (score 6):

Platforms may choose to define the behavior, but the C Standard does not require that they guarantee anything about it.  While historically microcomputer compilers have relatively consistently behaved as though -INT_MIN would yield INT_MIN or in some cases a number that behaves like a value one larger than INT_MAX, it has become more fashionable to instead have it *retroactively* change the value of whatever was being negated.  Thus, given:

```
int wowzers(int x)
{
  if (x != INT_MIN) printf("Not int min!");
  return -x;
}
```

a hyper-modern compiler may use the expression -x to determine that x can't
have been equal to INT_MIN when the previous comparison was performed, and
may thus perform the printf unconditionally.

Incidentally, gcc 8.2 will use the UB-ness of negating INT_MIN to "optimize" the following

```
int qq,rr;
void test(unsigned short q)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=q; i++)
    {
        qq=-2147483647-i;
        rr=qq;
        rr=-rr;
    }
}
```

into code that unconditionally stores -2147483647 to `qq` and 2147483647 to `rr`.  Removing the `rr=-rr` line will make the code store -2147483647 or -2147483648 into both `qq` and `rr`, depending upon whether `q` is zero.

Comment: Do you have supporting evidence for the hypothesis for hyper-modern compilers?

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal: I have identified situations where evaluation of an expressions that would cause overflow with certain argument values will cause compilers to infer that such arguments will not be received.  I haven't identified cases in today's compilers where negation of INT_MIN in particular would cause that, but the authors of compilers like gcc make very clear that they make no promises about future behavior in cases not mandated by the Standard and aren't explicitly documented.

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal: I added an example of a function where attempting to negate a value equal to `INT_MIN` in gcc 8.2 will affect the stored value of another object.

Comment: Woah—nice example!

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal: Even more interesting is the compiler's behavior if `q` is changed to `-2147483646-i`.  The generated code ends up being less efficient than if the `rr=-rr` line were replaced with `rr=-(unsigned)rr`, so the compiler's treatment of UB doesn't even improve code efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

> Is negating INT_MIN undefined behaviour?

Yes, when `INT_MIN < -INT_MAX` - which is **very** common (2's complement). It is *integer overflow*.

```
int i = get_i();

#if INT_MIN < -INT_MAX
if (i == INT_MIN) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Houston, we have a problem\n");
  // Maybe return or exit here.
}
#endif 

int j = -i;
```

[Houston, we have a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston,_we_have_a_problem)